# How to Pass an array through SWRevealViewController?

Tags: objective-c, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'd like to pass an array through the `SWRevealViewController` so that the array is accessible in my **sw_rear** `TableViewController`.

Previous solutions to this problem invoke modifying the **prepare for segue** section of the `SWRevealViewController.m` file. However, the **prepare for segue** block of code has been deprecated in the most up to date version.

How do I declare an array for the class and how do I pass data to this array from a different view controller?

Specifically the `ViewController` that calls **sw_rear** has an array myArray that I would like to be accessible to the `ViewController` that gets called when one of the menu items in **sw_rear** is selected.

What part of the `SWRevealViewController.m` file do I modify to do this?

Comment: How you are passing array previously ? can you post that code here ?

Comment: I do not know how to modify the Obj-c code of SWRevealViewController so currently I am not passing any array. The previous solutions suggested using the prepare For segue block, but it is commented out on SWRevealViewController. The full code is in SWRevealViewController on github